# Issues in Date string in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, string, nsdateformatter

I am working on an iPhone app. I'm using `NSDateFormatter` to format a date in `NSString`, then I tried to set that date string to `UILabel`. I tried this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
Result: theDate:16/10/2012
```

But I get an error:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
lbl.text = theDate; // the error comes here
```

Error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b837e0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Now i update my question, please read again

Comment: From your error it seems that your variable "theDate" is modified some where since it is showing NSCFArray, so please check that you are not modifying theDate somewhere else.Even just before assigning value to label you can log the value of "theDate" on console.

Comment: this error message is not on the `lbl.text`.....it is some where else

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 30)];
    lbl.text = theDate;
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

it is working